# Give all newly created files permissions not working (ACL)

Tags: permissions, acl

I'm trying to make all newly created directories AND files within a directory inherit the parent's directory permissions, but somehow it's not working.

[image: -R for recursive, -d for default, -m is the mask, g for groups, u for users and o for other.]

So I try to use ACL to give all subdirectories of /home/user/ 777 permissions. The newly created folder "testing" inherits the permissions correctly, but the file does not. My question is why? What should I do to make all files inherit the permissions too?